# jquery event.stopPropagation() doesn't seem to be working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a replica treeview using an unordered list. I dynamically append to this list using ajax, and create child lists. I have used event.stopPropagation() to prevent the parent event from firing, but am unable to prevent grandparent events from firing. Here is my code.

```
$('.child').click(function(event) {    

var uid = $(this).attr('id').substring(10);      
alert($('#childnodes' + uid).html());  
var childProd = //an ajax command is here which gets list items          
$(this).append(childProd);           
$('#span' + uid).text('-');
$('#childnodes' + uid).unbind();
$('.child' + uid).bind('click', child);
$('#childnodes' + uid).bind('click', parent);

event.PreventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
 });

function parent(event) {

alert("The parent fired.");

if (event.target != this) {
   return true;
   } 

var uid = $(this).attr("id").substring(10); 
$('#span' + uid).text('+');
$('#childnodes' + uid).unbind();       

$('#childnodes' + uid).childnodes().empty();
$('#childnodes' + uid).text('');
$('#childnodes' + uid).bind('click', child);

event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();

}

function child(event) {     
 if (event.target != this){     
   return true;
 } 

 var uid = event.target.id.substring(10);
 var childProd = //ajax command which I retrieve list items.

  $('#childnodes' + uid).append(childProd);           
  $('#span' + uid).text('-');      
   //unbind the event
   $('#childnodes' + uid).unbind();
   $('#childnodes' + uid).bind('click', parent);
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();  
   }
```

So essentially I start with this list

- Item A
- Item B
- Item C

Then I expand one of them with a click event

- Item A
- Item A1
- Item A2
- Item B
- Item C

I can click Item A1 and ItemA2 and only trigger their events to get this

- Item A
- Item A1
- Item A1B
- Item A2
- Item B
- Item C

Now the problem is if I hit Item A1B (a grandchild element) I then trigger Item A's delete event. Does anyone have any suggestions for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that the function named 'child' was never properly bound to my children. Thus the event wasn't barred from propagating, because the the functiont hat prevented this was never bound to the columns in the first place.

In short I was missing this line: `$('.child' + uid).bind('click', child);`

But no one would really notice because my code was a bit difficult to understand. I am going to work on this. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is hard to read with the indentation you provided.

The best I can tell is that you've mis-spelled a function name `PreventDefault()` just before one of the `stopPropagation()` calls, so I'm guessing execution fails at that point, and `stopPropagation()` is never reached.

These lines:

```
event.PreventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

should be:

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

(Notice the lowercase "p" in `preventDefault()`.)

Check the console. There are likely error messages. The one I get in Safari is:

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'event.PreventDefault' [undefined] is not a function.
```

---

**EDIT:** Also, currently the `stopPropagation` is *not* called if `(event.target != this)`.

If you *always* want `stopPropagation` called, then add that line to the top of the function. Otherwise when you `return true`, the rest of the code doesn't get called.

Comment: Hmm...I tried cleaning up my code a bit. I apologize that it is so messy; I'm new to jQuery and it often comes out messy when I use it. I admit that I did make a mistade with PreventDefault() but I still am getting the same error, even with the fix...

Comment: @Daniel - So according to your code, you do want the event to bubble if `event.target != this`. Is that right?

Comment: no, I don't. I read that putting that in would help stop an event from bubbling; I may have misunderstood (my apologies). I did, however, take that code out and am still getting the same error...

Comment: @Daniel: A `return` statement immediately exits the function. Doing `return false;` will (in jQuery) stop propagation. Trouble is that you're doing `return true;`, and you're doing it *before* the `stopPropagation()` call is reached. If you *always* want propagation stopped, place the `stopPropagation()` calls at the *beginning* of the functions.

Comment: hmm...I switched both return true to return false, and set event propagation to the beginning of the method...but it still doesn't work...I'm not sure if there's something about how the DOM tree works that I'm missing...

Comment: @Daniel: Not sure what the issue is then. A click event simply bubbles up from the element that received the event, up to the `document` level. Any element in that path that has a handler for the event can stop the bubbling with `event.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: @Daniel: I do see that you have a `childnodes()` method. There's no such method in jQuery.

Comment: hmm...I don't know how I came up with that. Maybe it's a javascript method. I replaced it with .children, and received no luck. then I commented it out, and all the proceding lines that dealt with removing childnodes, and still no luck. I am very confused as well.

Comment: I just figured out the problem. It was because I was missing this line in the 'child' function: 
$('.child' + uid).bind('click', child);

Thus I never bound the event that stops propagation, to the child rows. Thank you so much for your help!